# Unexpected behaviour in inner TextBlock (TextBox) in DataGridCell after "undo changes"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have editable cells in my DataGrid and I need to create "**undo changes**" button which sets original value to cell's **TextBlock**.

[image: My DataGrid]

I change color after changing value of TextBlock
[image: I change color after changing value of TextBlock]

Clicking "undo changes" button
[image: Clicking "undo changes" button]

Now there is **expected** value
[image: Now there is expected value]

But after clicking on cell, there is **unexpected** "**new**" value
[image: But after clicking on cell, there is "new" value]

[image: Unexpected "new" value]

Is there possibility that DataGridCell has **two different** TextBlocks (or TextBoxes)? And if so, why is it possible, that one of them rewrites another?

Here is part of my code where I do "undo changes"

```
private void ContextMenuDeleteItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var cellInfo = this.CurrentCell;
  this.ScrollIntoView(cellInfo.Item);
  var row = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cellInfo.Item) as DataGridRow;
  if (row != null)
  {
    FrameworkElement element = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    KeyValuePair<DataGridColumn, DataGridRow> key = new KeyValuePair<DataGridColumn, DataGridRow>(cellInfo.Column, row);
    if (originalCellValues.ContainsKey(key))
    {   
      ((element.Parent as DataGridCell).Content as TextBlock).Text = originalCellValues[key];
      (element.Parent as DataGridCell).Style = (element.Parent as DataGridCell).Column.CellStyle;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to catch this behaviour while debugging, in my **OnBeginningEdit** values are fine and then suddenly in **OnCellEditEnding** values are unexpected

In my OnBeginningEdit I save original values

```
protected override void OnBeginningEdit(DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.editableColumns[e.Column.DisplayIndex])
  {
    if (!e.Row.IsNewItem)
    {
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
  }

  FrameworkElement element = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
  KeyValuePair<DataGridColumn, DataGridRow> key = new KeyValuePair<DataGridColumn, DataGridRow>(e.Column, e.Row);
  if (!originalCellValues.ContainsKey(key))
  {
    originalCellValues.Add(key, ((element.Parent as DataGridCell).Content as TextBlock).Text);
  }
}
```

In my OnCellEditEnding I change style of cell - color cell if it was edited

```
protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  if ((e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text != originalCellValues[new KeyValuePair<DataGridColumn, DataGridRow>(e.Column, e.Row)])
  {
    FrameworkElement element = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
    (element.Parent as DataGridCell).Style = CreateStyle("RequiredColor", e.Column.CellStyle);
   }
  else
  {
    FrameworkElement element = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
    (element.Parent as DataGridCell).Style = e.Column.CellStyle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I added Mode=TwoWay where I bind properties on TextBlock value. It acted like it was TwoWay by default, but not in this case. Really strange behaviour.

```
<Controls:FilterableDataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding GarantList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserAddRows="True"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                    CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                    CanUserResizeRows="False"
                    CanUserSortColumns="True"
                    HeadersVisibility="Column"
                    SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                    SelectedRow="{Binding ActualRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                    AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource AlternatingRowBackground}"
                    UserContextMenu="{Binding DataGridContextMenu}"
                    IsSaveChanges="{Binding IsSaveChanges, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Controls:FilterableDataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Column1" Width="{StaticResource CheckColumnWidth}" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_ColumnCheck}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CheckColumnStyle}"/>
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_Identifikace}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource C_SPStyle}" Binding="{Binding GEx}" SortMemberPath="GEx" IsEditable="False" />
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_IndAktiv}" Width="{StaticResource IndicationColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource IndicationColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding IndAktiv}" IsEditable="True" />
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_Jmeno}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding JmenoUz, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEditable="True" />
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column5" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_Telefon}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding TlfUz, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEditable="True" />
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column6" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_Mobil}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding MobilUz}" IsEditable="True" />
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column7" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_Mail}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding MailUz}" IsEditable="True" />
              <Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column8" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_PristupovaUroven}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding CPu}" IsEditable="True" />
            </Controls:FilterableDataGrid.Columns>
          </Controls:FilterableDataGrid>
```

Here in Binding:

```
<Controls:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column5" Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.Label_Telefon}" Width="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnWidth}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ShortTextColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding TlfUz, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEditable="True" />
```